# Navigation is loosing the menu when pushing into navigation page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I Have a content page which is as follows and displays but i am loosing my hamburger menu as I am pushing it using the following. I am using the standard master detail app in xamrian.

So my main question is how do i push to the content page from my code behind without loosing the hambuger menu? As when I use push

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"

              xmlns:telerikGrid="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.DataGrid;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.DataGrid"
    xmlns:telerikPrimitives="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Primitives"
    xmlns:telerikInput="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Input;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Input" 

                 x:Class="FuelStockApp.Views.StockScanning">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout>

                <telerikInput:RadButton x:Name="btnTestScan" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" Clicked="BtnTestScan_Clicked"  Text="Test Scan" />


                <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid x:Name="gridItems"  SelectionMode="Single"   ItemsSource="{Binding Boms}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                    <telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>
                        <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="StockItemID"  HeaderText="StockItem" />
                        <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                        <telerikGrid:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" />
                        <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Actions" HeaderText="Scan Item">
                            <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <telerikInput:RadButton 
                         Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="40" Text="Scan Item" x:Name="btnScanItem" Margin="0, 2, 0, 0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                         BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White" />

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                        </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="Edit" HeaderText="Edit Item">
                            <telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <telerikInput:RadButton 
                         Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="40" Text="Edit Item"   x:Name="btnScanItem" Margin="0, 2, 0, 0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                         BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White" />

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellContentTemplate>
                        </telerikGrid:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid.Columns>

                </telerikGrid:RadDataGrid>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
```

Here you can see I am using

```cs
    private async void BtnFindBom_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string result = await dataTransFer.GetIsAliveState();        
        await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new StockScanning(txtBomId.Text));

    }
```

Showing my main page being set.

```cs
    public App()
    {
          InitializeComponent();
          DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
          MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
```

My Main Page code from above.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                xmlns:views="clr-namespace:FuelStockApp.Views"
                x:Class="FuelStockApp.Views.MainPage">

        <MasterDetailPage.Master>
            <views:MenuPage />
        </MasterDetailPage.Master>

        <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
            <NavigationPage>
                <NavigationPage.Icon>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                        <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_feed.png"/>
                    </OnPlatform>
                </NavigationPage.Icon>
                <x:Arguments>
                    <views:StockTransfer />
                </x:Arguments>
            </NavigationPage>
        </MasterDetailPage.Detail>

    </MasterDetailPage>
```

Comment: you are using PushModalAsync - this pushes a modal (dialog) on top of the existing content.  And for a MasterDetail you typically want the navigation to happen just on the detail, not the entire page

Answer (score 0):

Here you use *modal* navigation, not the *hierarchical*.

According to Microsoft documentation: [Hierarchical Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical), it says that:

> The NavigationPage class provides a hierarchical navigation experience where the user is able to navigate through pages, forwards and backwards, as desired.
>
> To navigate to page, it is necessary to invoke the PushAsync method on
>   the Navigation property of the current page.

So you have to change your code with `PushModalAsync(...)` method to `PushAsync(...)`.